# How to save canvas image in .net core 2.1

Tags: html5-canvas, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to send a javascript canvas blob image by capturing from video element to my controller method in ASP.NET Core 2.1.

I have successfully captured image and from captureimage function i am passing blob to controller, I'm using this code:

and from controller action method i don't know how to save the image.

thanks for help.

```
          function captureimage(){

            var video = document.querySelector(videoId);
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
            //trigger the registered vall back with the blob
            canvas.toBlob(
              var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("image", blob);

            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: `Info/SaveImage',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formdata
              }).then(function () {

               });
            );

    public async Task<ActionResult> SaveImage(IFormFile image)
    {
          //how to save from IfromFile.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> i don't know how to save the image

It depends on where you want to save the image.

For saving to server disk, you could try code like below:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    // full path to file in temp location
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```

For saving image byte to database, try code like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if  (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser {
          UserName = model.Email,
          Email = model.Email
        };
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await model.AvatarImage.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            user.AvatarImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    // additional logic omitted

    // Don't rely on or trust the model.AvatarImage.FileName property 
    // without validation.
}
```